# In axis and allies 1941 do fighters have to take off to participate in an attack?

Tags: axis-and-allies

ON the UK players turn he attacks a Japanese destroyer in sea zone 32 with a UK carrier(carrying 1 UK and 1 US fighter) from sea zone 29. I know that if the carrier gets destroyed, the US fighter is also destroyed,since its a guest fighter. But can the UK fighter land somewhere in friendly territory (say in the Phillipines which would be 2 spaces from sea zone 32 because it already moved 2 from sea zone 29), or is it also treated as cargo and destroyed since it did not take off? Different example. And if the previous is a valid attack, (lets say UK fighter now in India), can during the combat move the fighter land on the UK carrier in sea zone 29, the carrier with fighter on it move to attack the destroyer in sea zone 32, gets destroyed,(the jap destroyer is sunk also), can the UK fighter now use its final movement to land on Borneo? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: This is a very difficult question to follow.  I'd edit it to make it clearer, but I can't figure out what you're actually trying to say in some parts.

Comment: Thats ok, i already got it.

Comment: If you clean it up, I'd be happy to upvote it.  Upvotes get you reputation which lets you do more on the site.

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle is that an air unit ends its turn when it "lands" on a space or a carrier. So if a fighter flies two spaces, fights, and lands on a carrier with its third space, its turn ends, and it cannot fly to an adjacent fourth space if the carrier is attacked. (The air unit is refueling while this happens.)

However, an air unit on a carrier can defend its carrier, which is to say that a player can choose to take fighters as casualties before, or instead of the carrier. (If the carrier is UK, and a fighter is US, the UK player needs the consent of the US player.) But most players will sacrifice a fighter to allow the carrier to be taken as a casualty last, because if it is sunk, the fighters are lost anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your own air units don't move with carriers. They start the turn airborne in the sea zone. If they want to be in the same sea as the moved carrier, they have to move there. So, if you don't want them in the battle, just leave them in their original sea zone until the battle is over. If the carrier survives, land them during the non-combat phase. If the carrier dies, fly them to a friendly territory.